# using gmtime() via Python's ctypes

Tags: python, datetime, ctypes

I'm trying to access C's `gmtime()` function from Python to avoid `datetime.datetime. fromtimestamp()`,  as it seems to be consuming a lot of time when I try to convert a large column of timestamp long values. This is what I have:

```
from ctypes import *
libc = CDLL('msvcrt.dll')
gmtime = libc.gmtime
gmtime([any timestamp I try])
```

I get `17181872` no matter what number i put in.

> OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x0098967F

I must be making some noob mistake, but I can't figure it out. Can someone point out my error?

**EDIT:**

replacing the last line with:

```
gmtime(byref(c_int64([any timestamp I try])))
```

doesn't solve the problem - I get  `17181872` in response for any number I put in. Any ideas?

Comment: What are you passing into gmtime?

Comment: seconds from the epoch as Long values

Comment: gmtime wants a pointer to that value, not the value itself.

Comment: Might it be that the pointer is not to an int, but something else? I still get weird results using byref(c_int64())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definition of `gmtime`:

```
struct tm *gmtime(const time_t *clock);
```

so you need to provide a pointer:

```
tm = ctype.c_int64(1505656543)
gmtime(ctypes.byref(tm))
```

The return type of `gmtime` is a pointer to a structure:

```
class TimeStruct(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("tm_sec", ctypes.c_int),
        ("tm_min", ctypes.c_int),
        ("tm_hour", ctypes.c_int),
        ("tm_mday", ctypes.c_int),
        ("tm_mon", ctypes.c_int),
        ("tm_year", ctypes.c_int),
        ("tm_wday", ctypes.c_int),
        ("tm_yday", ctypes.c_int),
        ("tm_isdst", ctypes.c_int),
    ]
gmtime.restype = ctypes.POINTER(TimeStruct)

time_data = gmtime(ctypes.byref(ctypes.c_int64(1505656543)))
print(time_data.contents.tm_hour)
```

But it is not necessary to do this all by ourself. `time.gmtime` is a very thin wapper around the C function `gmtime`. I doubt you can get it any faster, than using that.

Comment: This sounds right, but I keep getting 17181872 in response for an value I put inside gmtime(byref(c_int64()))

Comment: Python's gmtime() did turn out faster than going via ctypes, but the experience was quite enlightening, I feel more comfortable with ctypes now. Thank you.